# Is it wise to use Google Tables as a Database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, google-fusion-tables, unhosted

I just found out about the [Unhosted Movement](https://unhosted.org).

I understand the points being made about the advantages over the *classical* web app approaches including a database being a sql or non-sql database.

From my point of view there are concerns regarding security and privacy. I believe the disadvantages outweigh the advantages. Especially if sensitive Data is involved.

I would love to hear about more pros/cons and experiences from you guys. Personally I would rather use Laravel/RoR or a similar Framework with scaffolding etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm about to try that. As far as security/privacy is concerned, you can grant limited access to tables and use ssl. Google still knows everything of course.

But fusion tables isn't a full blown database after all. Its sql is highly limited, you have no joins in SELECT, no GROUP BY in views and only left outer joins, no subqueries, no EXISTS clause, no users/transactions/locking/isolation levels etc, what might be the reason to use a database in the first place. It is also [not meant to be that](http://googleresearch.blogspot.co.at/2009/06/google-fusion-tables.html). There are also no standard connectors I'm aware of, so you'll have to use the API. The last post [asking for a JDBC driver](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fusion-tables-users-group/N2R-rOVXUjE) is some years old, and there still isn't any.